# Upgrading the SQL Extensions Toolkit in netezza

Tags: netezza

How to upgrading the SQL Extensions Toolkit in Netezza? I don't want to have duplicate files I just want to upgrade from the SQL Ext I have currently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Latest packages are available in fix central
Install instructions ->
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/t_sqlext_installing.html 
and https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/t_sqlext_enabling.html

You might find it easier to install SQLToolkit in its own database and refer to the functions from that database.

Comment: When you install functions in a separate database, the ‘PATH’ can be set to make things easier to maintain:
Https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS5FPD_1.0.0/com.ibm.ips.doc/postgresql/udfdev/c_udf_cross_db_access.html